# Initialize entire char array

Tags: c, arrays, char, initialization

I thought this would be easy, but google searching isn't turning up what I'm looking for. In C, how do I initialize an entire char array to a particular char, say, `'N'`? This is what I tried:

```
char test[256] = {'N'};
```

But this only initializes the first index to `'N'` and the rest to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset):

```
#include <string.h>

char test[256];
memset(test, 'N', 256);
```

Comment: Note: You *cannot* use `test` initialized in this way as string because there are no terminating null-character in the array.